# Temporarily freeze Erlang process remotely?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Is there a way to temporarily freeze (forcefully temporaily pause execution) an erlang process remotely? So not by sending a message that the process receives and stops execution until it gets an unfreeze message, but something more invasive.

Whenever I do live reloads locally, some process ends up calling a function while it's temporarily unloaded. I'd very much like to avoid those crashes, so I thought about remotely freezing some processes, like `SIGSTOP` does on linux.

Comment: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#suspend_process-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a suspend function which can do the trick.

```
erlang:suspend_process(PidOfTheProcessToBeSuspended)
```

you can later resume the process by calling

```
erlang:resume_process(PidOfTheProcessToBeResumed)
```

https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#suspend_process-1